# Create Table In HTML/PHP From Query Results

Tags: php, html, html-table, datatable

I am trying to use a mix of php and html to create a table to display my query results.  This is what I have

```
<body>
<?php
if ($sql) {
?>
<div id="dvdata">
   <table id="example" >
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>January </th>
            <th>February </th>
            <th>March </th>
            <th>April </th>
            <th>May </th>
            <th>June </th>
            <th>July </th>
            <th>August </th>
            <th>September </th>
            <th>October </th>
            <th>November </th>
            <th>December </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
<?php
foreach ($sql as $res) {
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>" . $res->salesPerson . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . "$" . number_format(round($res->January)) . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . "$" . number_format(round($res->February)) . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . "$" . number_format(round($res->March)) . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . "$" . number_format(round($res->April)) . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . "$" . number_format(round($res->May)) . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . "$" . number_format(round($res->June)) . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . "$" . number_format(round($res->July)) . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . "$" . number_format(round($res->August)) . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . "$" . number_format(round($res->September)) . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . "$" . number_format(round($res->October)) . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . "$" . number_format(round($res->November)) . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . "$" . number_format(round($res->December)) . "</td>";
        print "</tr>";
    }
}
?>
</table></div>
```

And I've included these links to generate the datatable

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-2.2.4/pdfmake-0.1.27/dt-1.10.15/af-2.2.0/b-1.3.1/b-colvis-1.3.1/b-flash-1.3.1/b-html5-1.3.1/b-print-1.3.1/cr-1.3.3/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.2.1/r-2.1.1/rg-1.0.0/rr-1.2.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-2.2.4/pdfmake-0.1.27/dt-1.10.15/af-2.2.0/b-1.3.1/b-colvis-1.3.1/b-flash-1.3.1/b-html5-1.3.1/b-print-1.3.1/cr-1.3.3/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.2.1/r-2.1.1/rg-1.0.0/rr-1.2.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Now when my data displays on screen the issue is that I get a header row as I want, but instead of showing an individual row for each `salesPerson` I get one row that has all of the data jammed into that one row.

My desired output is one row for each month for each `salesPerson`

Comment: It would have to be something in your css. There is nothing in your php code to indicate that the rows would all be on the same html table row.

Comment: just my luck.  Thanks for confirming.  I was hoping it was something stupid of me like needing to iterate the ``salesPerson`` to create a new row

Comment: Your `<tr></tr>` is the html table row and you have that. If they are not going vertical, then the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: However there could be something in the values thats breaking the structure. View the rendered source from your browser (usually ctrl + U)

Comment: right, that's what made me think I needed an additional ``foreach`` because I only have one ``<tr></tr>`` but I should have at least 6 rows in my table since there are 6 employees that I am trying to output data for

Comment: The output data does not contain any characters that would interfere with the structure

Comment: Then comment out your css and see what happens.